# Data seeding not happening after publish

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The seeding routine is not being run after I publish my website. I have enabled updating the DB and indeed the DB is built and all migrations applied when I first run the application after the publish, however no data is seeded.

All migrations and seeding work fine when instigated manually.

I have two virtually identical projects, one is using EF6.0.2 and everything works fine with this project (i.e. seeding happens after publish).

The second project uses EF6.1.1 and the seeding does not happen after publish.

This now looks like it has something to do with the Web Deploy wizard not detecting that I am using DB Migrations and not even giving me the choice of Executing Code First Migrations when application starts (instead I get the option to Update DB).

Anyone got any idea why it is not detecting the fact that I am using Migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason that the seeding was not running after deploy was because Web Deploy had not detected that I was using Migrations and was not allowing me to enable Execute Code First Migrations on App Start as part of the deploy (instead it was just allowing me to select Update DB which only runs the migrations and does not run the seed method!)

I still have no idea why web deploy was not detecting Code First Migrations (I have posted a second question about that), but I do have a manual solution to overcome this problem.

I manually edited the Publish Profile and removed the following lines

```
      <Object Type="DbDacFx" Enabled="True">
        <PreSource Path="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=QSAT;Integrated Security=True" includeData="False" />
        <Source Path="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AutoScripts\QSATDBContext_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac" dacpacAction="Deploy" />
      </Object>
      <UpdateFrom Type="Web.Config">
        <Source MatchValue="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=QSAT;Integrated Security=SSPI;" MatchAttributes="$(UpdateFromConnectionStringAttributes)" />
      </UpdateFrom>
```

and replaced them with

```
      <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
        <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="Data.QSATDBContext, Data" MigrationConfiguration="Data.Migrations.Configuration, Data" Origin="Configuration" />
      </Object>
```

And now it all works.